# Select * from Select

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Its very weird situation I know, nut I have got myself into it somehow. I have to connect to some other system service by passing some parameters in url.

In their service they are creating some query using parameter I pass.

For my case I have to pass 'Select' as a parameter name which is actually some class name on their side. So they end up in creating query as `Select * from select`
and some condition.

On execution I am getting error response as:

> 'There was a syntax error in a SQL query or filter expression at line
>   1, position 186.  Saw \"Select\" but expected
>   '..SQL: \"SELECT col1, col2 FROM Select AS D where
>   some condition.

Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: `Select` is a **reserved word**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Select` is reserved word, you have to escape it by enclosing in backticks characters in order for MySQL to process your query:

```
select * from `select`
```

Comment: or even better, dont use reserved words as tablenames

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Surely, but OP has written " I have to pass 'Select' as a parameter name" so I suppose he can't change it in this particular case

Comment: Yes, I know that. Your solution is ok, but OP shuold solve the underlying problem. If he is calling a service, then the problem is on the way the service side is creating the query. I can sense the sql injection from here ;)

Comment: service side guys have deployed some changes for this, and now i am able to get data. But still this is a good option to apply in case we have to write solution for these kind of issue.

Answer (score -1):

Its recommended not to use MySQL reserved keywords.. but if its necessary there is a solution..

Use this, it will work for you :

```
select * from yourdatabasename.select
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it may be useful when we are creating service or sql query in our application itself. However in my case its a third party service I am calling, so this solution will create unnecessary tight coupling scenario. And also I am not sure if the application will share schema and database name with me.